# How to use jQuery special events in delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to setup a jQuery special event to debouce a double click:

```
(function($){
  $.event.special.submitclick = {
    setup: function(){
      console.log('setup', this, arguments);
      $(this).on('click', clickAction);
    },
    teardown: function(){
      $(this).unbind('click', clickAction);
    }
  };
  var clickAction = _.debounce(function(ev){
    $(ev.target).triggerHandler('submitclick');
  }, 300, true);

})(jQuery);
```

While this code work for normal targeted click:

```
$("#xx").on("submitclick", function(){
  console.log(this.id + ' target click');
});
```

It does not work on delegated click:

```
$("#wrap").on("submitclick", "#xx", function(){
  console.log(this.id + ' delegated click');
});
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/locikihe/1/edit) as an example.

How should I setup such that it also work on the delegated call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) only invokes the handlers bound to a specific element. Event bubbling does not take place, so event delegation cannot work.

Use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) instead:

```
var clickAction = _.debounce(function(ev) {
    $(ev.target).trigger("submitclick");
}, 300, true);
```